# Python, как запустить jar файл из скрипта при этом не остановив его

Tags: python, python-3.x, jar

Хех, так вот, я запускаю (консольный) jar файл из скрипта Y, но при этом скрипт останавливается. Как мне сделать так что бы (консольный) jar файл запускался отдельно от скрипта?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ту часть кода, где Вы запускаете jar файл из скрипта

Answer (score 3):

Два варианта:

---

```
import os
pid = os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, "/bin/mycmd", "mycmd", "myarg")
```

---

```
from subprocess import Popen
pid = Popen(["/bin/mycmd", "myarg"]).pid
```

Если нужно, чтобы запущенный файл смог работать после завершения процесса-родителя, то используйте `Popen` с дополнительными флагами

### Дополнение:

[Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.spawnl) рекомендует использовать модуль `subprocess` вместо функций `os.spawn*` 
Там же отмечено, что некоторые функции семейства spawn отсутствуют под Windows

> spawnlp(), spawnlpe(), spawnvp() and spawnvpe() are not available on Windows.

Comment: Ошибка, если кратко то вот: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'spawnlp'

Comment: @Terrorka, Вы правы, под Windows такой функции нет. Добавил информацию в ответ

Comment: Так что вообщем делать?)))

Comment: Используйте второй вариант - с модулем `subprocess`

Comment: Аналогично, только ошибка другая(она слишком большая) Если кратко то:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ту часть кода, где Вы запускаете jar файл из скрипта

Comment: Я уже сделал костыль))) (У меня есть бат файл в котором запускается JAR, а потом снова скрипт)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Подробное руководство]

При экспериментах с Java и Python я делал так